# How to manage 2 DAO methods in a single transaction in Java Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao, transactional

I'm building a new dynamic website and I created 2 DAO class in Spring MVC to manage the query in 2 different tables.
I need to know how can i manage 2 DAO methods in a single transaction, using Hibernate...Pratically, I create 2 DAO Java classes and related implementation class:

First DAO class (FirstDAOImpl.java):

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void insertUser(User user) 
{
    //do insert an user using hibernate...
}
```

Second DAO class (SecondDAOImpl.java):

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void insertUserRole(UserRole register) 
{
    //do insert user role using hibernate...
}
```

In my Spring controller, i need to call both DAO method in a single transaction...

Actually, I have a new transactional method for any DAO method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertNewUser(Model model) 
    {
        //Other code
        try
        {
            firstDAO.insertUser(myUserObject);
            secondDAO.insertUserRole(myUserRoleObject);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.info("exception!");
        }
        //Other code
    }
```

When the method `insertUserRole()` to insert a new record fails, the transaction for the previous method `insertUser()` is executed succesfully without rollback!

How can I manage these 2 methods in a single transaction? I would keep separates these 2 operations...

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the DAO methods from another method with `@Transactional`.

The transaction will then be created outside of the DAO methods, and they will use the existing transaction (due to the default propagation) instead of creating their own new ones.

Comment: thanks!! can you explain your post with a simple code please? :)

Comment: Uh, sure... `@Transactional void myMethod() { dao1.method(); dao2.method(); }`. Modify to suit your needs, and read up on transactions. They're both tricky and very important to understand.

Comment: thanks so much man! :) one thing: the dao1 and dao2 methods should be transactional also?

Comment: It depends completely on how you intend to use them. That's why I said `read up on transactions`. They're not a simple thing.